# Неожиданный результат программы

Tags: c++

Всем известно правилльность следующих утверждений:

- int(1.13) == 1;
- 1.13 - 1 == 0.13;
- 0.13 * 100 == 13;

Почему же в программе:

```
constexpr double d = 1.13;
int t = (d - int(d)) * 100;
cout << t;
```

**выводится 12** ?

Comment: Заголовок поправьте. Код не ошибочный и ничего не доказывает. Выведите на печать `d - int(d)`.

Comment: @Эникейщик  да, код не ошибочный, заголовок неудачный. Но тогда нужно подсказать какой заголовок лучше подошел бы.

Comment: ヒミコ  почему теряется точность при умножении?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, где-то видео было, я его несколько раз смотрел, там про мантиссу очень многое говорилось, и еще сайт есть, но увы... ссылки у меня нет.

Comment: Реально `double x = (d - int(d)); printf(%.14e %.17e\n", x, x)` печатает `1.30000000000000e-01 1.29999999999999893e-01`. Т.о. наблюдаемая "ошибка " это правильный результат (`int z = x * 100` даст 12, а не 13). Наблюдаемые при печати double переменной округления происходят именно при форматном выводе

Comment: @Эникейщик, я бы сказал: выведите    cout << setprecision(10) << d;

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c67812fe369b0911